# my datetime recorded in my DB shift of 2 hours compared to my javascript variable

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

Everytime I save my date time into my database, I clearly see a shift of 2 hours in my database.

I know this is something about UTC but I prefer keeping the exact date in my DB without UTC.

Here is my code:

```
var now = "06/08/2013 20:18"; // Eigth of june 2013
myObservable(now);
```

Then I check my database (sql server) and I see `2013-06-08 18:18:00.000`.

**My question**: how to record the current date time in my sql server table?

PS: I'm ok to use moment but I did not succeed with it (still have a shift).

Comment: If the problem involves your database, you'll have to show some code about what exactly comes from the browser, and how it gets put in the database in the server-side code.

Comment: Also, when you say "I prefer keeping the exact date in my DB without UTC" - recognize that your local time zone offset is probably going to change twice a year when daylight saving time starts and stops.  When it starts, there is a one hour gap in the timeline, and when it stops, there is an hour that is duplicated.  This ambiguous hour is difficult to track with a simple `DateTime` field.  If you don't want to store UTC, and you want it *exact*, then you need to use `DateTimeOffset`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation:

```
function today() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd } if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm } today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy + ' ' + h + ':' + m;
    return today;
};

var now = moment.utc(today(), "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm").toDate();
myObservable(now);
```

This time, the variable now contains: `Sat Jun 08 2013 23:08:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)`

And the value in my database is `2013-06-08 21:08:00.000`.

This value recorded in my DB is the real date time for now.

---

UPDATE

To respond to John, *show some code about what exactly comes from the browser, and how it gets put in the database in the server-side code*

With the solution I suggested myself:

```
var now = moment.utc(today(), "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm").toDate();
// now <- Sun Jun 9 10:40:00 UTC+0200 2013
myObservable(now);
```

- The browser send: 2013-06-09T08:40:00Z
- The date recorded in DB: 2013-06-09 08:40:00.000

This is the real date time.

PS: here the time is: 08:40.

---

With a simple case:

```
var now = new Date();
// now <- Sun Jun 9 08:45:54 UTC+0200 2013
myObservable(now);
```

- The browser send: 2013-06-09T06:45:54.676Z
- The date recorded in DB: 2013-06-09 06:45:54.677

This date is shifted of 2 hours compared with the real date.

---

*recognize that your local time zone offset is probably going to change twice a year when daylight saving time starts and stops....*

I don't need to track these time offset, our app will be used locally.

*This ambiguous hour is difficult to track with a simple DateTime field. If you don't want to store UTC, and you want it exact, then you need to use DateTimeOffset*

So I tried with a `DateTimeOffset` field type as you suggested and below is the result:

```
var now = new Date();
// now <- Sun Jun 9 08:54:12 UTC+0200 2013
myObservable(now);
```

- The browser send: 2013-06-09T06:54:12.843Z
- The date recorded in DB: 2013-06-09 06:54:12.8430000 +00:00

This date is shifted of 2 hours compared with the real date. The problem is still the same.

Tested with Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Comment: This code is so overly repetitive, I don't know where to start.  You have basically put a big wrapper around getting the current date.  Since you end up with a native JS date, you might as well just say `var now = new Date()`.  What do you expect to achieve by splitting it out in string components just to reassemble it again?

Comment: I updated my question to show you more details. I need to have the date recorded in my DB exactly the same as showed on my watch :) without any UTC added. My suggested answer do the job but I wonder if there is a better way. Thanks.

Comment: You still didn't show any of your server-side code, so I can't help you.  I'm assuming you are using .Net on your web server, so you need to show your .Net code.  The Javascript is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Also, your comment "I don't need to track time offsets, our app will be used locally" - that is a common misconception.  Even when working locally, you will have two different offsets to consider - unless you happen to be running somewhere that never changes their clocks for daylight saving time.  Most places do.